Sampling a parquet file with only one row_group
I am working on a huge  parquet file containing over 30 million rows. I only need a small portion of it and wish pick a number of randomly selected rows. When i inspect the file's metadata, there's only one row_group which means I can't use pyarrow's read_row_groups to select random groups.
pf = ParquetFile('Flight_Delay.parquet') 

  created_by: parquet-cpp-arrow version 6.0.1
  num_columns: 30
  num_rows: 30132672
  num_row_groups: 1
  format_version: 1.0
  serialized_size: 15701


an example::: duckdb -c "select * from parquet_scan('Downloads/bank_failures.parquet') USING SAMPLE 10;"

using the above suggested example, here's a couple of runs of that
duckdb -c "select * from parquet_scan('Downloads/bank_failures.parquet') USING SAMPLE 10;"
┌───────┬──────────────────────────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│  c1   │               Bank               │     City      │    State     │    Date    │         Acquired by          │ Assets ($mil.) │
│ int64 │             varchar              │    varchar    │   varchar    │    date    │           varchar            │     double     │
├───────┼──────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│   100 │ Partners Bank                    │ Naples        │ Florida      │ 2009-10-23 │ Stonegate Bank               │           66.0 │
│     2 │ Legacy Bank                      │ Scottsdale    │ Arizona      │ 2011-01-07 │ Enterprise Bank and Trust    │          151.0 │
│   103 │ Home Valley Bank                 │ Cave Junction │ Oregon       │ 2010-07-23 │ South Valley Bank and Trust  │          252.0 │
│    44 │ MetroPacific Bank                │ Irvine        │ California   │ 2009-06-26 │ Sunwest Bank                 │           80.0 │
│   108 │ Bank USA, N.A.                   │ Phoenix       │ Arizona      │ 2009-10-30 │ U.S. Bank, N.A.              │          213.0 │
│    77 │ Piedmont Community Bank          │ Gray          │ Georgia      │ 2011-10-14 │ State Bank and Trust Company │          201.7 │
│    53 │ Bank of Wyoming                  │ Thermopolis   │ Wyoming      │ 2009-07-10 │ Central Bank and Trust       │           70.0 │
│     4 │ Doral Bank                       │ San Juan      │ Puerto Rico  │ 2015-02-27 │ Banco Popular de Puerto Rico │         5900.0 │
│   148 │ Allegiance Bank of North America │ Bala Cynwyd   │ Pennsylvania │ 2010-11-19 │ VIST Bank                    │          106.0 │
│   115 │ Butte Community Bank             │ Chico         │ California   │ 2010-08-20 │ Rabobank, N.A.               │          499.0 │
├───────┴──────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴────────────────┤
│ 10 rows                                                                                                                    7 columns │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
$ duckdb -c "select * from parquet_scan('Downloads/bank_failures.parquet') USING SAMPLE 10;"
┌───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│  c1   │                  Bank                   │      City       │   State    │    Date    │           Acquired by            │ Assets ($mil.) │
│ int64 │                 varchar                 │     varchar     │  varchar   │    date    │             varchar              │     double     │
├───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│    15 │ Main Street Bank                        │ Northville      │ Michigan   │ 2008-10-10 │ Monroe Bank and Trust            │           98.0 │
│     5 │ Edgebrook Bank                          │ Chicago         │ Illinois   │ 2015-05-08 │ Republic Bank of Chicago         │           90.0 │
│    35 │ Strategic Capital Bank                  │ Champaign       │ Illinois   │ 2009-05-22 │ Midland States Bank              │          537.0 │
│     9 │ First Community Bank                    │ Taos            │ New Mexico │ 2011-01-28 │ U.S. Bank, N.A.                  │         2300.0 │
│    20 │ Citizens Bank of Effingham              │ Springfield     │ Georgia    │ 2011-02-18 │ Heritage Bank of the South       │          214.0 │
│    38 │ Desert Hills Bank                       │ Phoenix         │ Arizona    │ 2010-03-26 │ New York Community Bank          │          497.0 │
│     5 │ Premier American Bank                   │ Miami           │ Florida    │ 2010-01-22 │ Premier American Bank, N.A.      │          351.0 │
│    27 │ Western Springs National Bank and Trust │ Western Springs │ Illinois   │ 2011-04-11 │ Heartland Bank and Trust Company │          186.0 │
│   126 │ First Security National Bank            │ Norcross        │ Georgia    │ 2009-12-04 │ State Bank and Trust             │          128.0 │
│    93 │ Irwin Union Bank and Trust Company      │ Columbus        │ Indiana    │ 2009-09-18 │ First Financial Bank, N.A.       │         2700.0 │
├───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┤
│ 10 rows                                                                                                                               7 columns │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

hope this is of help ....
